# Upload image to server in Java

Tags: java, jsp

i want to upload an image file to server, and i've uploaded successfully to server.But i have a "images" folder in my project's folder, and i want to save image in this folder. How can i do it?

Comment: Move the file once you uploaded it

Comment: What's the problem?  Are you trying to figure out what the path should be?  Or perhaps trying to figure out how to move a file via java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are having trouble finding the path to your folder ?

- In a JSP use
  String path = application.getRealPath("/images");
- In a Servlet use 
  String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");